# WCF issue or event handling issue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a class called MyServiceHost.vb:

```
public class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    private Dictionary<int, Service> _activeClients;

    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
}
```

After that in another form I want to have the second line in my other form I defined these lines:

```
_host = new MyServiceHost(typeof(Service));
            _host.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(_host_MessageReceived);
            _host.Open();
```

How to write them in Vb.net please help, the followings does not seem to work:

```
_host = New MyServiceHost(GetType(Service))
    _host. += New EventHandler(Of MessageReceivedEventArgs)(AddressOf _host_messageRecieved)
```

Also note that my MyServiceHost.vb class looks like this:

```
Dim _activeClients As Dictionary(Of Integer, Service)
Public Event MessageReceived As EventHandler(Of MessageReceivedEventArgs)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you try following [C# to VB conversion utility](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)?

Comment: yes still no work. I cannot reach messagerecieved event in my form in vbcode

Comment: I'm not sure if this help, but [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/8eb6f396-1774-49f7-9ac5-29797947ad92) was similar issue with WCF conversion from C# to VB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
AddHandler _host.MessageReceived, AddressOf _host_messageRecieved
```